# Can not iterate through Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have the following object (return from Insomnia)

```
[
  {
    "field": 10.5,
    "this_is_a_bool": 1,
    "name": "",
    "data": "2018-05-22T03:00:00.000Z",
    "field2": null
  },
  {
    "field": 5.3,
    "this_is_a_bool": 0,
    "name": "Slim Shady",
    "data": "2020-01-22T04:45:00.000Z",
    "field2": null
  }
]
```

The problem is that I can't iterate over those "set of values" so I can edit them.

To do something like this:

```
for (const val in myObj) {
   if (val.field2 === null) {   
      val.field1 = 'flag - ' + val.field1
   }
}
```

What I've tried:

`for (const val in myObj)`
`for (const val of myObj)`
`const [key,value] of Object.entries(myObj)`

Errors: Sometimes it says `myObj is not iterable` and sometimes the code is just ignored.

Comment: What is `myObj` here?

Comment: I guess that you're trying to iterate array of objects and not the single object.

Comment: You want to change a const?

Comment: @palaѕн myObj is the first code.

Comment: assuming myObj is pointing at the array, why are you not using forEach? It would be better to see more code.

Comment: @Alex we can not re-assign a const variable, but we can change it's attributes values.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @epascarello I read in another thread that `forEach` could be a "bad practice" and may be fail sometimes. Since then I was just trying to use `for in/of`.  I may be wrong

Comment: @epascarello Also, when I try that it returns `myObj.forEach is not a function`.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro then something is wrong in your code. Show more code. You clearly do not have an array so there is something wrong with how you are retrieving and reading it.

Comment: Add some basic debugging: `console.log(myObj);for (const val in myObj) { console.log(val); }` - "*somtimes the code is just ignored*" - looks like *sometimes* myObj is not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use simple `.map()`:

```js
const src = [{"field":10.5,"this_is_a_bool":1,"name":"","data":"2018-05-22T03:00:00.000Z","field2":null},{"field":5.3,"this_is_a_bool":0,"name":"Slim Shady","data":"2020-01-22T04:45:00.000Z","field2":null}],

    result = src.map(({field, field2, ...rest}) => ({
      field: field2 === null ? `flag-${field}` : field, 
      field2,
      ...rest
    }))
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

or... if you still want using for loop...
(in your sample val is key)

```js
var myObj = [
  {
    "field": 10.5,
    "this_is_a_bool": 1,
    "name": "",
    "data": "2018-05-22T03:00:00.000Z",
    "field2": null
  },
  {
    "field": 5.3,
    "this_is_a_bool": 0,
    "name": "Slim Shady",
    "data": "2020-01-22T04:45:00.000Z",
    "field2": null
  }
];
for (const val in myObj) {
    if (myObj[val].field2 === null){
        myObj[val].field = 'flag - ' + myObj[val].field;
    }
}
console.log(myObj);
```